# Problem with wkhtmltopdf or css size (A4, mm, in)

Tags: css, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf through the Symfony Bundle [knp Snappy bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle) and it works fine as long as I'm using px for size.
But I need to generate a sticker sheet based on A4 size and I can't have anything right : 
I set all margin to 0 for wkhtmltopdf

```
$snappy->setOption('margin-top', '0mm');
$snappy->setOption('margin-left', '0mm');
$snappy->setOption('margin-right', '0mm');
$snappy->setOption('margin-bottom', '0mm');
```

then in my test html (it's a twig in the application) for a  columns:
i've tried a simple :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0">
  <div style="background-color:red;width:99%;height:1400px;border:solid #000 1px">
    <div style="background-color:green;display:inline-block;padding:0;margin:0;width:105mm;height:297mm"></div>
    <div style="background-color:yellow;display:inline-block;padding:0;margin:0;width:105mm;height:297mm"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i've also tried with inches : 105 => 4.13in, 297mm => 11.69in
with the same result

I've also tried to generate directly (without the bundle)

```
wkhtmltopdf --page-size A4 -B 0 -L 0 -R 0 -T 0 test.html output.pdf
```

with the same result

This is what i get : 
[image]

why half the A4 size: 105mm or 4.13in is not working?
I've also tried setting directly the page size in the wkhtmltopdf setup : 
page-height and page-width with no change.

I can't use percentages because with the real data I will have more complex settings (margin left and right, 2, 3... columns)

What could be wrong about the setup?
is it a CSS problem ? a wkhtmltopdf problem?

Answer (score 9):

I found out that using the `--disable-smart-shrinking` option helped a lot. 
By default the `--enable-smart-shrinking` is activated and messes with the html rendering, when using absolute measures (in, mm) 
[link to doc](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt)

Comment: Solved my issue too, thank you. Also make sure the zoom is not set to other values, default is 1.
`'zoom' => 1,  'disable-smart-shrinking' => true,`