# wkhtmltopdf scales down css dimensions

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy, phpwkhtmltopdf

I'm experiencing a similar issue that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640593/problem-with-wkhtmltopdf-or-css-size-a4-mm-in/61014798#61014798) one with the latest update of the knp Snappy Bundle on Symfony 4.4.5.

I've set the following options and they do not help to fix the error.

```
options:
    - { name: 'no-outline', value: true }
    - { name: 'encoding', value: 'UTF-8' }
    - { name: 'dpi', value: 300 }
    - { name: 'orientation', value: 'Portrait' }
    - { name: 'page-size', value: 'A4' }
    - { name: 'page-width', value: '210mm' }
    - { name: 'page-height', value: '297mm' }
    - { name: 'margin-top', value: '0' }
    - { name: 'margin-bottom', value: '0' }
    - { name: 'margin-left', value: '0' }
    - { name: 'margin-right', value: '0' }
    - { name: 'disable-smart-shrinking', value: true }
```

**Note:** Changing `'disable-smart-shrinking'` to `'enable-smart-shrinking'` changes nothing. Adding the `zoom` option changes nothing either.

I have checked if the options do have an effect at all and I can confirm that they have. As en example, I changed `'Portrait'` to `'Landscape'`, which indeed resulted in a landscape document.

Here is a test document showing the issue:

[image]

The blue box is the PDF that is generated by the snappy bundle. It has the correct dimensions of `210mm x 297mm`, the red-border box is the result of a div with the CSS dimensions of `210mm x 297mm`. There is clearly something off.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score -1):

**Short answer:**

You are probably using a version of *wkhtmltopdf* without the qt patches
To fix this, you need a patched version of *wkhtmltopdf* and use the same parameters you wrote in your post

---

**Long answer:**

To know if you are running a version with or without the patches.

Just run `wkhtmltopdf` command. If you see something like this:

> Reduced Functionality:
>
> This version of wkhtmltopdf has been
> compiled against a version of QT without   the wkhtmltopdf patches.
> Therefore some features are missing, if you need   these features
> please use the static version.
>
> Currently the list of features only supported with patch QT
> includes:
>
> - Printing more than one HTML document into a PDF file.
> - Running without an X11 server.
> - Adding a document outline to the PDF file.
> - Adding headers and footers to the PDF file.
> - Generating a table of contents.
> - Adding links in the generated PDF file.
> - Printing using the screen media-type.
> - Disabling the smart shrink feature of WebKit.

That means that you are running a non-patched version of wkhtmltopdf.

To be able to use *smart-shrinking* or *zoom* feature, you need a patched version.

---

PS: I know the thread is old but I hope this will help someone

Comment: I'm running a version with header/footer features and it still scales down the content.